# Elegant way to remove some keys from nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I want to delete the following 'date' and 'last_modified' keys from the following nested dictionary. Kindly suggest any elegant way to do this dynamically with in Python.

```
{
   "total_pages":1,
   "datasets":[
      {
         "dataset_name":"enterpriseqa-landing-zone_census2017",
         "database":"enterpriseqa-landing-zone",
         "table":"census2017",
         "owner":"qadataengineer",
         "zone":"landing",
         "date":"2020-06-09T07:11:25+00:00",
         "location":"s3://enterpriseqa-landing-zone/static/census2017/",
         "count":"5507",
         "classification":"csv",
         "last_modified":"2020-06-09T07:15:49+00:00",
         "type":"Static"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
keys = ["date", "last_modified"]
[[d.pop(key) for key in keys] for d in dictionary["datasets"]]
```

Where dictionary is your dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

If `d` is your dictionary from the question, you can use this example to delete the keys:

```
for dataset in d['datasets']:
    del dataset['date']
    del dataset['last_modified']
```

Produces this dictionary:

```
{
    "total_pages": 1,
    "datasets": [
        {
            "dataset_name": "enterpriseqa-landing-zone_census2017",
            "database": "enterpriseqa-landing-zone",
            "table": "census2017",
            "owner": "qadataengineer",
            "zone": "landing",
            "location": "s3://enterpriseqa-landing-zone/static/census2017/",
            "count": "5507",
            "classification": "csv",
            "type": "Static"
        }
    ]
}
```